# gasoline lawn mower in French

Tags: vocabulaire

What would you call a "gasoline lawn mower" in French?

I know that lawn mower is "tondeuse à gazon f".

Could it be "tondeuse à gazon à essence f"?

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In France, you will often find:

> Tondeuse à gazon thermique

(short for "à moteur thermique")

See [French Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tondeuse_%C3%A0_gazon#Tondeuse_.C3.A0_moteur_thermique).

In Switzerland and Canada you might find:

> Tondeuse à gazon à essence.

I would say that both are correct. In fact, the second is more straightforward.

My guess is that the rather convoluted use of "thermique" was dictated by the double use of "à" in "**à** gazon **à** essence", which is intuitively disgraceful to the ear.

I have also seen:

> Tondeuse à gazon essence,

where the second "à" has been dropped, which is business language, not regarded as grammatically standard. Which tends to reinforce the point that the French language dislikes such a repetition.

Answer (score 0):

As @fralau said, in Canada we would say,

> Tondeuse à gazon à essence.

We could also say,

> Tondeuse à gazon motorisée.

However, in actual conversation, "Tondeuse à gazon" or even just "Tondeuse" are assumed to be referring to a gasoline lawn mower unless it is otherwise specified.

Comment: “Tondeuse (à gazon) motorisée” or just “tondeuse (à gazon)” could also mean an electric mower.

Comment: @Gilles I agree it could, it's just (at least in my locality) it would undoubtedly be assumed to be gas powered unless it was specified that it was electric.  But maybe this isn't the case everywhere.  :)

Comment: Fellow Canadian here. I always assume gas powered unless otherwise specified.